# Is there a way to autocomplete @username without typing the whole thing?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, comment-replies

To notify another user when I am making a comment I type @*username*. I notice, though, that a little box pops up to tell me who I am matching. After reading [this helpful answer on how comment replies work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/284743), I understand that I wouldn't need to type the whole username in order to notify that person. However, as a matter of style (or perhaps respect to that person's name) I often want to use the full username.

When the username matching box pops up, it feels like an autocomplete box. It seems like I should be able to press Enter or Space or something to finish it. But I can't. Am I missing something?

Comment: I never get the pop-up box after typing the @ symbol (even after typing a few characters. Am I missing something? Does it only work on some browsers? Is there a setting I've missed? I'm using Chrome.

Comment: @SimonBosley, In Firefox I get a popup for your user name after typing "@S" and I can complete it then using the Tab key. I don't currently have Chrome available for testing.

Comment: I've tried this on IE version 11 and it doesn't work either. Is there a special modifier key you press when entering the '@' symbol as well? I'm starting to think this is a practical joke and there is no auto-complete! Maybe there is a user setting or required rating?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I'm running Ubuntu Linux and haven't tried it in IE. I would be surprised it if didn't generally work for all browsers but you could ask a new question about it in meta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can press tab to complete the name, or, click on it.

Answer (score 1):

I had almost completed my question when I stumbled on the answer, so I will just post them both at the same time.

**Answer:** click on the pop up box with your mouse to autocomplete the username.

**Suggestion to StackExchange developers:** Make <kbd>Enter</kbd> also work to autocomplete so that I don't have to take my hands off the keyboard.

**Update:** Thanks to @MuertoExcobito for the full answer (use <kbd>Tab</kbd>)

Comment: This has never worked for me. I don't get a popup, and TAB just goes to the next fields.

Comment: @u84six, Do you start it with the `@` sign?

Comment: It's funny you mention, because I came across this page just to figure out why it wasn't working, and realized that it doesn't work with the user who owns the answer! Doh! I suppose it makes no sense since the user who owns the answer will always get the notification. So all this time I thought it was broken because I didn't know the user would always get the notification on a comment haha! I dont' use SO all that much ;)

Comment: @u84six. Ok, that's good you understand now. I didn't know that it didn't work for the owner.