# More standard way of navigating nick reply autocompletion list

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts, autocomplete

When you start replying to a comment, an autocompletion list appears. You can use <kbd>tab</kbd> to accept the autocompletion. But this was totally non-obvious to me. I only learned I could use <kbd>tab</kbd> because I found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296514/is-there-a-way-to-autocomplete-username-without-typing-the-whole-thing). The last time I've used <kbd>tab</kbd> to autocomplete was in an Unix terminal, years ago.

There's a standard in *graphical* (as opposed to terminal) UIs on how to do this. It's followed with minor differences in:

- MS Visual Studio
- the Google Chrome omnibar (address bar)
- the Gmail to-address field
- In, I think, any autocompletion context I've ever used except for a Unix terminal

For example in Visual Studio the procedure is as follows:

- Type a function name in the code editor
- The autocompletion list appears, and none of its items are selected.
- Pressing the <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> keyboard keys selects the first item. You can then use these two keys to navigate the list.
- If and only if an item is selected, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key confirms (executes) the autocompletion.

It'd be great if Stack Exchange supported this way of interaction.

Comment: I edited to make it more clear that this isn't a dupe.

Comment: Oops, I should've posted this to meta.SE, not meta.SO. Someone migrate it please?

Comment: Tab is also pretty standard for autocomplete: It works in IntelliJ, Firefox address bar, Gmail to-address, and pretty much any other autocompletion context _i've used_, including a Unix terminal..

Comment: What JonasCz said, the `tab` key comes from `bash` (or possibly an earlier shell, i'm not that old, sorry).  Changing it might get some heavy resistance from *U&L*, *superuser* and *serverfault*.  I admit that `tab` was the obvious key for me the first time i needed the autocomplete.

Comment: @JonasCz: So let's support both ways, so everyone is happy :)